# Load 2 different content pages for the administrator and the user

Tags: php

I'm seeking advice on conceptual site structural design rather than specific code.

**Situation**

I'm building an article page, where the administrator and the user would see the same content.

However the administrator can use more functions such as editing the article, blacklisting comments and replying to posts. These would be realized by buttons set within the article.

**Question**:

Should I load 2 different sets of pages for the administrator and the user, or use the same page, but add in some if-else statements to make it show differently?

Thanks a lot,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In practice, I use if statements to decide whether or not to display a link/button to an action.  Here is some pseudocode that may be of help:

```
if (user.roleType == RoleType.Administrator)
{
  //show button/link for admin-only privilege
}
```

You can use that piece of code for everything that is admin-only.  In addition, I add another security check to the page(s) that have admin-specific content, so if an end-user somehow gets the URL to an admin-only area, they will be stopped by the page-specific security check.

Answer (score 0):

If extra features are just an extra link or button on a page go with option two you don't want to have to maintain both pages if you need to change something.

If the extra feature is a separate page that one or the other type of user would require then make them separate.